# Comparing shrunk model vs null model?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, regularization

I have a null model $M_0$ with parameter $\theta$ and a more general model $M_1$ with parameters $(\theta,\alpha)$. I know that $M_0=M_1$ for $\alpha=0$.  I am estimating $M_1$ using a penalized likelihood method and $M_0$ using maximum likelihood estimation. How can I compare $M_0$ and $M_1$? Can I use AIC?